# powershell start-process as admin, am i misssing something

Tags: windows, powershell

Im trying to create a script where a domain user would be able to run IIS service on windows as a local admin using stored credentials.

```
$adminerpath = 'c:\programdata\adminer'

Function StoreCreds(){
    $credential = Get-Credential
    $credential | Export-CliXml -Path  $adminerpath\data.dat
}

if (Test-Path $adminerpath){
    $credential = Import-CliXml -Path $adminerpath\data.dat
    Start-Process C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe -Credential ($credentials)
}

else {
    New-Item -Path $adminerpath -ItemType "directory"
    attrib +h c:\programdata\adminer | Out-Null
    StoreCreds
    }
```

very simple, should see if the credential is stored and then run process with -credential.
it works with anything else (like note.exe or pwoershell.exe), but when i try running this with InetMgr.exe im getting:
start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The requested operation requires elevation.
any help would be much appriciated

Comment: Ive managed to this this: 
$cmds = {"C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe"; "exit";}
Start-Process powershell -Credential ($credential) -ArgumentList $cmds

that way it works, is this the correct way thoug?

Comment: You are passing the credentials of an admin account in with the -credentials param, however that isn't going to run an elevated session. That will just run the session as that admin account. Have you tried using the -Verb RunAs param on the end? that tells Start-Process to elevate the session. I have not tried it with the -credential param though